# Dynamic transpose of rows to column without pivot (Number of rows are not fixed all the time)

Tags: sql, pivot-table, exasol

i have a table like

```
a 1
a 2
b 1
b 3
b 2
b 4
```

i wanted out put like this

```
1 2 3 4 
a a
b b b b
```

Number of rows in output may vary.

Pivoting is not working as it is in exasol, and case cant work as it is dynamic

Comment: The traditional CASE solution with GROUP BY does work. Try it.

Comment: Do you mean that the number of rows varies or the number of columns?